# Python: library to handle localization for addressing/refering first/second/third person

Tags: python

Is there some Python library, where you could have text to be localized according to its language rules? Mainly when referring to person?

Maybe something similar as `num2words` library?

For example, let say we have this source text in English.

`Dear Jonas Jonaitis,`

In English, its simple, because you don't need to change anything, whether you are using first person or third person.

But in Lithuanian language, for example, it is not correct and sounds weird.

So `Gerb. Jonas Jonaitis` would be incorrect.

Correct way would be `Gerb. Jonas Jonaiti` (`Gerb.` part would be handled by translation, but `Jonas Jonaitis` part is actually not translation as it is name of a person).

Basically, rule should know how to handle text when you refer in first person for example.

Comment: Assuming that the number of reserved words and languages is limited - why dont you have your own dict to handle it?

Comment: @balderman its not words, but rules. As there could be any name person has, so dict would not help. So in my example, `Jonas Jonaitis` would be `Jonai Jonaiti`, but let say another person called `Darius Kvedaravičius`, could not be called same as `Jonas Jonaitis`. It would be `Dariau Kvedaravičiau` (see different ending). I guess I can invent my own rules, but I was wondering if there is some project like that already.

Comment: Got it - I am not aware of any library that is able to help.